# What is the term for this non-paperclip technique?

Tags: terminology

As a schoolboy, when we did not have access to staplers or paperclips, we would fold down the corner of the paper and tear a small notch in the fold with our fingers in order to keep papers together.

What is the term which describes this technique ?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here they call it, [nick and fold](https://lifehacker.com/5526365/bind-paper-without-staples-using-a-clever-fold):

> - Every so often, you need to keep papers together in proper order, but a stapler or clip can't be found. This ***nick-and-fold technique*** keeps up to 15 sheets together, and requires only the use of your fingers.

[image]

(lifehacker.com)

Answer (score 1):

There may be other colloquial terms for this ad hoc way of keeping a few sheets of paper together, but I’ve always heard it termed [*dog ears* or *dogeared*.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dog_ears) It may be imprecise, since the diagonally folded over corner of a book page, whether by accident or design, can also be called a dog ear, but no one thought to call it “dog ear with torn tab.”

[image]